# Similarity Amongst Recipes Using Ingredients and Reviews/Descriptions

Tags: distance-functions

I'm still toying with things and just learning this, so please forgive any incorrect terminology.

My toy data set is a collection of recipes with a fairly significant overlap in ingredients. I'm using these as my features, and using Pearson squared distance as described in *Programming Collective Intelligence* to determine the correlation between recipes. I'm not looking to "train" anything; I currently would just like to compare the recipes in my corpus and find $X$ nearest and $Y$ farthest neighbors.

I thought it'd be fun to expand this, and include people's reviews/comments on the recipes as part of the distance calculation, leading to a closer association between recipes that were both described as "sweet" or "tart" or "sour". I don't know how to do this along with the other features though; I've found examples of bags-of-words for similarity, but I can't seem to find any information about combining it with other features.

Is this a valid approach, and is there some terminology that I should be looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Cool idea! Welcome to CV. I bet any answers we might be able to offer here would go over well at [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) too. That is, any answers here might provide many answers there too!

Comment: You could think of it this way: you have a distance $d_1$ between recipes in terms of the ingredients and a distance $d_2$ in terms of the reviews. You could weight them in different ways and define a combined distance $d_1 + \lambda d_2$. Then you have to choose an appropriate $\lambda$. You can either try things out until you get something reasonable or be more formal and use cross-validation to choose $\lambda$. See the chapter in Segaran on knn and the wines example where he does exactly this.

Comment: That seems so simple. In my case it'd be the less formal side since I don't believe there would be a "right" answer, but this looks promising. As I'm using Pearson correlation coefficient right now I guess I need to look into other distance measurements that are additive?